# pointers and memory addresses

Tags: c, pointers

I recently did an assignment using bit masking and shifting to manipulate a 4 byte int.

I got to wondering if it was possible to set a char pointer to the start of the int variable and then step through the int as if it was a 1 byte char by using the char pointer.

Is there a way to do this or something similar?  I tried to set the char pointer to an int but when I step ahead by 1 it jumps 4 bytes instead.

Just trying to think of alternative ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can, this code shows the behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int value = 1234567;
  char *pt = (char*) &value;

  printf("first char: %p, second char: %p\n", pt, pt+1);
}
```

This outputs:

```
first char: 0x7fff5fbff448, second char: 0x7fff5fbff449
```

As you can see difference is just 1 byte as intended, this because arithmetic on pointers has been done after casting the type to a smaller kind of data.

Comment: Ahhh, I see where I was going wrong now.  Needed to do proper casting to make it work.  Makes sense now.  Thanks Jack/mfrankli/Martin

Comment: "Of course" is a bit of an exaggeration. It's actually not obvious, and it's a special property guaranteed by the C language that `char` pointers can be used to examine/access other types. It's only valid for `char`; other pointer types are not allowed to alias like this.

Comment: No, it's valid for other types. I could cast it to a `short*` and navigate them 2 bytes by 2 bytes. I said of course because casting will just force the compiler to think that a type is what I want it to be, this will cause errors if I'm going wrong but I have no limitations.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine this should do what you want:

```
int x = 42;
char *c = (char *) &x;
char byte0 = c[0];
char byte1 = c[1];
char byte2 = c[2];
char byte3 = c[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes a char pointer would step by 1byte at a time, you probably inadvertently cast it to an int.

Another complexity is the order of the bytes in an int, at least on Intel